# global scope vs file scope

Tags: c++, scope, global-variables

What is right to say about global variable:

If it is declared without `static` keyword:

1. It has `file scope` and `external linkage` OR
2. It has `program scope` and is visible to all files in the program

If it is declared with `static` keyword:

1. It has `global scope` and `internal linkage` OR
2. It has `file scope` and `internal linkage`

And how is global namespace scope related to this?

This notions are really confusing altough i think I understand how it works, but at different places they call it in different ways so i don't know which is right.

Answer (score 1):

The answers for the first question are both incorrect.

The variable will have extrenal linkage indeed but will be visible in other program units only if it is declared in it.

As for the second question then indeed the variable will have file scope and internal linkage.

Any variable declared outside some explicitly specified namespace is considered as declared in the global namespace. Variavles with external or internal linkage can be declared in any namespace including the global namespace.

We are speaking about variables that are declared outside any function.

Comment: For the first question, first answer: I mean it has file scope `but` it can be `referred to` from other translation unit by declaring it as `extern`. So the confusion arises when using the notions of file and global scope. Is it right to say file scope and external linkage or global scope and if we want to refer to it from other translation unit we declare it so we can use it?

Comment: It can be said that a variable has a global scope. But at the same time it can be declared in any namespace,